# click on ok on windows pop up during exe installation through powershell

Tags: powershell

click on ok on windows pop up during exe installation through powershell

Start-Process -FilePath $"filepath" -ArgumentList "/S" -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have forgotten to ask a question - please [review the relevant help center content](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76211345/edit) with the question you want to ask and any relevant details :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

CMD Silent switches depend on the Developer and therefore you should read the docs of that certain app to find the silent/passive install switches.
Some Apps dont have proper silent switches but you could use for example AutoHotKey to automate the mouseclicks if needed.

I would write as following:

```
$Filepath = "\\FILESERVER\FOLDER\FILE.exe"
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "$filepath /S" -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
```